# Exchange Server 2003 Bcc problem

Tags: email, exchange-2003

It's only recently been brought to our attention that BCC(blind carabon copy) emails arn't being deliverd locally.

We can send out emails with bcc emails but if someone tried putting our organisations email as the bcc it fails. Although by the looks of the System Message Tracker:

[http://cs-sol.swan.ac.uk/~cs440361/help.png http://cs-sol.swan.ac.uk/~cs440361/help.png](http://cs-sol.swan.ac.uk/~cs440361/help.png)

That it reaches our server but doesnt get any further apart from a post master message being generated. CC seems to be working ok.

Not quite sure what to try any ideas?

Comment: What does it say in the NDR?

Comment: What do you mean by NDR? sorry not came across that term before